# Event bubbling with jQuery's mouseout, prematurely hiding

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

I'm having a jQuery problem and I can't wrap my mind around what's wrong. I suspect it's something with media bubbling but i'm not sure. I've changed the mouseout listener from foo, plym-flyout, and first.. all seem to hide as soon as the mouse enters.

It works if I listen on a class separate from the menu it works fine. Also I'm not sure if some of the CSS being absolutely positioned has anything to do with this.

Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/vrCKU/

```
<ul class="plym-flyout" style="display: none;">
    <ul class="foo">
        <li class="first"><a href="">My Entries</a></li>
        <li><a href="">I'm Watching</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Leaderboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="">My Tickets</a></li>
        <li><a href="">My Account</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="">Refer Friends</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="plym-dropShadow"></ul>
</ul>
```

-- JS --

```
$(".hdr-user").click(function () {
    $(".plym-flyout").toggle();
});

$(".foo").mouseout(function () {
    $(".plym-flyout").hide();
});
```

Comment: Does the jsfiddle actually work for you? We don't have your images on there.

Comment: It works as far as replicating the issue, I forgot to mention I didn't  relink the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`:

http://jsfiddle.net/txA8r/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: Wow, perfect!, thanks so much =)

Would it be beneficial at all to nest the mouseleave listener inside of the click listener, so it's only listening after being clicked? Or does this not matter for performace?

Comment: The event is only bound once on DOM ready, so performance is not an issue in this case